# How to navigate to a webpage, input text and click on a button using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Could you please help me automate clicking a webpage button using Python and Selenium?

Here's an example of a Python code that I have so far, which opens the browser using my profile, goes to the webpage.
However, it never interacts with the page:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:/Users/mohamed.a.eshra/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data") #Path to your chrome profile

url = 'https://google.com/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/tools/selenium/chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)

driver.get(url)

inputtext = driver.find_element_by_name("Search").sendkeys("This is a test")
search = driver.find_element_by_name("btnk").click()
```

Could you please help me improve it to be able to click on a webpage button?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following code:

```
url = 'https://google.com/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/tools/selenium/chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
driver.get(url)
inputtext = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
inputtext.send_keys('This is a test')
inputtext.submit()
```